# vunit, what are reset conditions between test case

Tags: vhdl, vunit

I'm very confused about vunit testing, especially the link between tests and the way they are reset.

Please take a look at next minimal example:

#### device under test

Device has one inner state that latch on 1 when input goes to 1

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity dut is
    port(
        A : in  std_logic;
        B : out std_logic := '0'
    );
end entity;

architecture RTL of dut is
begin
    -- will latch when A goes to '1'
    -- stay 1 forever
    B <= '1' when A = '1';
end architecture;
```

#### testbench

- test1 : Dut inner state to '1'
- test2 : Dut has been reset in between test1 and test2
- test3 : Does not set dut inner state to '1' because C, which is set at start of process, but somehow reset to initial state (1) before test.
- test4 : Does not set dut inner state to '1' because D, which is set at start of process, but somehow reset to initial state (U) before test.
- test5 : Does not set dut inner state to '1' because E, which is set at start of **loop**, but somehow reset to initial state (U) before test. Which seems contrary to the [the documentation](https://vunit.github.io/run/user_guide.html#testbench-with-test-cases) (or most likely, I don't get it)
- test6 : Dut inner state is set, F is not reset.

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

library vunit_lib;
use vunit_lib.run_pkg.all;
use vunit_lib.check_pkg.all;

library libdut;
use libdut.all;

entity some_tb is
    generic (runner_cfg : string);
end entity;

architecture arch of some_tb is
    signal A, B, C : std_logic := '0';
    signal D, E, F : std_logic;
begin
    invdut: entity dut port map (A => A, B => B);

    F <= '1';

    main: process begin
        test_runner_setup(runner, runner_cfg);
        C <= '1';
        D <= '1';

        while test_suite loop
            E <= '1';

            if run("test 1") then
                check_equal(B, '0', "test 1.1");
                A <= '1';
                wait for 1 ns;
                check_equal(A, '1', "test 1.2");
            elsif run("test 2") then
                check_equal(A, '0', "test 2.1");
                check_equal(B, '0', "test 2.2");
            elsif run("test 3") then
                A <= C;
                wait for 1 ns;
                check_equal(B, '0', "test 3.1");
            elsif run("test 4") then
                A <= D;
                wait for 1 ns;
                check_equal(A, 'U', "test 4.1");
                check_equal(B, '0', "test 4.2");
            elsif run("test 5") then
                A <= E;
                wait for 1 ns;
                check_equal(A, 'U', "test 5.1");
                check_equal(B, '0', "test 5.2");
            elsif run("test 6") then
                A <= F;
                wait for 1 ns;
                check_equal(A, '1', "test 6.1");
                check_equal(B, '1', "test 6.2");
            end if;
        end loop;

        test_runner_cleanup(runner); -- Simulation ends here
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

#### Vunit file

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path
from vunit import VUnit

SRC_PATH = Path(__file__).parent / "src"
TEST_PATH = Path(__file__).parent / "test"

def create_testsuite(project):
    lib = project.add_library("libdut")
    lib.add_source_files(SRC_PATH / "*.vhdl")

    libuart_test = project.add_library("libdut_test")
    libuart_test.add_source_files(TEST_PATH / "*.vhdl")
```

## The question(s)

This seems very random to me. I will ask multiple question into one, because, most likely, they are tightly correlated.

When are the signal reset ?
Is every test run in a different simulation or are they "in series" with chances of side effect ?
In which foremost case, why is there a loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default VUnit will run each test case in a separate simulation but it is possible to change this behavior using the `run_all_in_same_sim` attribute. The rationale for this is described here: https://vunit.github.io/run/user_guide.html#running-test-cases-independently

Having the loop allow for this option but there are also other reasons as explained in https://vunit.github.io/run/user_guide.html#running-a-vunit-testbench-standalone. In general, https://vunit.github.io/run/user_guide.html is a good source for the details about VUnit execution.

The reason your signal assignments do not work as you expect is due to delta cycles. When A is assigned E in test 5 it is done in the same delta cycle as E is assigned 1 since nothing between the two assignments consume time. The new value of E is not present when A is assigned E. Instead A gets the previous value of E (U).

The difference between test 5 and 6 is that F is assigned 1 before the test_runner_setup procedure completes. A procedure can consume time and in this case it does, at least delta cycles. When A is assigned F the new value of F is present.

I'm not sure how well you know the concept of delta cycles and the difference between signals and variables. If not, I suggest that you look into that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would you mind also covering the reason why test 5 seems to act not as expected as per the part quoted from the manual in my question. Specifically, why is E reset while F from test 6 is not ? I can post another question on SO if you'd rather.